# facebook graph search intro/tour/guide like script

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

Okay I guess this question may seem too vague but I'm trying to find the script that helped user get to know the graph search for the first time, the help/guide/tour script which would automatically write something in searchbar & return result..if that ain't possible then I would like to get any script that would help me serve a tour for my website which would involve a bit of user input like typing in something & then continue with the tour/guide/help..
ps: I have used intro.js but I don't know how to have user input with that..
lastly I guess the topic title may be wrong..but believe me I have been digging for hours now & couldn't find the script & may be my English is poor :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out tourist.js it has features for users input -http://easelinc.github.io/tourist/

Comment: Try to flesh out your answer a bit more.  In its current state it is barely more than a link and might be deleted in the future.